# errores en la url rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

El proyecto ya esta en producion, quisiera saber como rederizar cada vez que salga un error de la url como el ejemplo de abajo, que salga una imagen o algo dicienfo que esa url no exite. gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ese error en producción no se ve, en su lugar se muestra la página 404 de rails, ¿deseas cambiar esa página?

Comment: @Gerry me puedes  ayudar con esta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/118237/error-al-ejecutar-rails-s-e-production-rails-5?noredirect=1#comment219682_118237  gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentarlo de la siguiente manera (esto es un ejemplo):

1. hay que borrar el archivo default que está en public, el archivo 404.html para evitar errores.
2. hay que modificar el archivo application.rb que está en config y en las rutas de la siguiente manera teniendo en cuenta tu proyecto:

   ```
   module NameOfMyApp
     class Application < Rails::Application

       require Rails.root.join("lib/custom_public_exceptions")
        config.exceptions_app = CustomPublicExceptions.new(Rails.public_path)
     end
   end

   Rails.application.routes.draw do
     match "/404" => "errors#error404", via: [ :get, :post, :patch, :delete ]

   end
   ```
3. Ahora, debes crear los siguientes archivos de la forma habitual y le agregas el html que quieres que se muestre en el error:

   lib/custom_public_exceptions.rb

   app/controllers/errors_controller.rb

   app/views/errors/error404.erb