# Error al ejecutar rails s -e production rails 5 ayuda

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`rails s -e production`

**la pagina esta bloqueada**

```
 => Booting Puma
 => Rails 5.1.4 application starting in production 
 => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
    Puma starting in single mode...
   * Version 3.10.0 (ruby 2.3.1-p112), codename: Russell's Teapot
   * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
   * Environment: production
   * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
    Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**production.log**

```
       F, [2017-11-17T13:25:39.813807 #18778] FATAL -- : [46e13b8b-08ba-47cb-8bd4-7c0a20096d3a]   
       F, [2017-11-17T13:25:39.813856 #18778] FATAL -- : [46e13b8b-08ba-47cb-8bd4-7c0a20096d3a] 
       ActionView::Template::Error (Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)):
       F, [2017-11-17T13:25:39.814028 #18778] FATAL -- : [46e13b8b-08ba-47cb-8bd4-7c0a20096d3a]     54:         
       [46e13b8b-08ba-47cb-8bd4-7c0a20096d3a]     55: 
       [46e13b8b-08ba-47cb-8bd4-7c0a20096d3a]     56:   <div class="panel-body">
       [46e13b8b-08ba-47cb-8bd4-7c0a20096d3a]     57:           <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), html: { role: "form" }) do |f| %>
       [46e13b8b-08ba-47cb-8bd4-7c0a20096d3a]     58:             <div class="form-group">
       [46e13b8b-08ba-47cb-8bd4-7c0a20096d3a]     59:              <center>
       [46e13b8b-08ba-47cb-8bd4-7c0a20096d3a]     60:               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
       F, [2017-11-17T13:25:39.814077 #18778] FATAL -- : [46e13b8b-08ba-47cb-8bd4-7c0a20096d3a]   
       F, [2017-11-17T13:25:39.814116 #18778] FATAL -- : [46e13b8b-08ba-47cb-8bd4-7c0a20096d3a] app/helpers/users_helper.rb:7:in `resource'
       [46e13b8b-08ba-47cb-8bd4-7c0a20096d3a] app/views/layouts/_navigation.html.erb:57:in `_app_views_layouts__navigation_html_erb__231458829_92193820'
       [46e13b8b-08ba-47cb-8bd4-7c0a20096d3a] app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:24:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___506764122_92229900'
```

**app/views/layouts/_navigation.html.erb:57**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:24**

```
  <body>
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
     <header>
      <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
     </header> 
    <main role="main">
        <%= render 'layouts/messages' %>  
        <%= yield %>
    </main>
  <% else %>
     <header>
       <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
     </header>
     <main role="main">
      <%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
      <%= yield %>
    </main>
   <% end %>
 </body>
```

Comment: Tienes que compilar los assets para producción. Revisa [la guía de rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) para ver como hacerlo

Comment: @AlterLagos Hola me puede ayudar con los pasos es que me equivoco , gracias

Comment: ¿en que te equivocaste?

Comment: @AlterLagos yo le di este comando y ya  no se como seguir RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails assets:precompile

Comment: ¿pero te salió algún error durante la ejecución del comando? ¿te sigue saliendo el mismo error de antes? ¿reiniciaste la app rails?

Comment: @AlterLagos yo le di el commando anterior me toco instalar otra cosa y salio esto                                                                                                yarn install v1.3.2
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
info Lockfile not saved, no dependencies.
Done in 0.26s.  y depues volvi y lo ejecute y siguio lo mismo